# Configure Bitbucket deployment to Azure Website with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to provision some Azure Websites using Powershell and am not sure how to configure Bitbucket deployment. Is this possible? Using the Service Management cmdlets I see that there is explicit support for Github deployment, but not Bitbucket. Perhaps there's a way using the new Resource Manager cmdlets, but there's very little documentation that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't yet present in the PowerShell New-AzureWebsite Cmdlet and can only be configured when provisioning a new Website via the Management Portal.

Comment: Simon, have you got a source for this information or any indication of whether this will be implemented soon?

Comment: The SDK and PowerShell Cmdlets source code is hosted on Github here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/ so you can see what's currently committed / in development for future releases. Nothing stops you forking the code and adding the features you need and then making a PR...